# Assigning random letters to variables, but each letter must appear either 2 or 4 times in Python

Tags: python, random

How do I assign random letters to variables and ensure that each letter must be assigned either 2 or 4 times? I have no problem with assigning random letters, but I'm having great trouble with the later part.

Here is my current code, which definitely has something wrong but I don't know how to fix it:

```
import random
import string
def assign():
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    n1 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n2 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n3 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n4 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n5 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n6 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n7 = random.choice(alphabet)
    n8 = random.choice(alphabet)
    
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
n1 = random.choice(alphabet)
n2 = random.choice(alphabet)
n3 = random.choice(alphabet)
n4 = random.choice(alphabet)
n5 = random.choice(alphabet)
n6 = random.choice(alphabet)
n7 = random.choice(alphabet)
n8 = random.choice(alphabet)   

if ((n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8).count(random.choice(alphabet))) != 2 or 4:
    assign()
else:
    print(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8)
```

How do I fix it so that whatever randomly assigned letter gets assigned to another variable or 3 more? (Assigned letters appear either 2 or 4 times).

Comment: Where `n9,n10,n11,n12,n13,n14,n15,n16` are come from, and what the problem do you try to solve? Why do you need multiple variables and not some kind of collection?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
import string
import random

number_of_variables_to_create = 8
print(
    [
        ''.join(
            random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
            for _ in range(random.choice([2, 4]))
            ) for _ in range(number_of_variables_to_create + 1)
    ]
)
```

Output: a list of `8` random string that are *either* `2` or `4` chars long. You can assign those strings to variables.

```
['JV', 'CRFQ', 'DA', 'KSPW', 'NVRB', 'MQOM', 'IB', 'QD', 'EU']
```

To add and access the variables, try this:

```py
import string
import random

number_of_variables_to_create = 8
strings = [
    ''.join(
        random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
        for _ in range(random.choice([2, 4]))
        ) for _ in range(number_of_variables_to_create + 1)
]


for idx, _string in enumerate(strings, start=1):
    globals()[f"n{idx}"] = _string

print(strings)
print(globals()["n1"])
```

Sample output:

```
['BZJV', 'EBYL', 'NW', 'IDVU', 'VUGJ', 'IP', 'PJ', 'HW', 'IE']
BZJV
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

First, your `if` condition is not doing what you think it does:

```
if ((n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8).count(random.choice(alphabet))) != 2 or 4:
```

To check, just try the following

```
>>> 1 != 2 or 4
True
>>> 2 != 2 or 4
4
>>> 3 != 2 or 4
True
>>> 4 != 2 or 4
True
>>> 5 != 2 or 4
True
```

The line first evaluates `x != 2`, which is always `True`, execpt for `2 != 2` which yields `False`. Next it evaluates `True or 4` yielding `True` (because integers larger than `0` are treated as `True`) or `False or 4` which in fact yields `4` (basically, if the first variable is `False`, then the `or` operator will just return whatever the second variable is).

What you are actually looking for is

```
if ((n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8).count(random.choice(alphabet))) not in [2, 4]:
```

The second thing is: you are leaving it up to chance a) how often each letter appears and b) which letter you are checking (counting). This means a) you have to repeat taking choices until it coincidentally matches your desired result and b) you might not detect your desired output, because you are counting the wrong letter.

You can fix this, by simply taking one choice and assigning it to multiple output variables. As an example, the following code will ensure the output contains 1 random letter twice and another letter 4 times. I will also avoid choosing the same letter twice, as this would yield 6 times the same letter, which is unwanted:

```
import random
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
c1, c2 = random.sample(alphabet, 2)
output = 2*[c1] + 4*[c2]
print(output)
random.shuffle(output)
print(output)
```

And the output will be something like

```
['V', 'V', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['V', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'V']
```

And if you really need an explicit list of many similar named variables (I advice against this):

```
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6 = output
```